# Asynchronous download with HttpClient: The text associated with this error code could not be found

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, c++-cx, windows-rt

I intend to use the following code to download a file. It works when WIFI is available; but when there is no Wifi, I expect to catch the exception raised in the `previousTask.get()`. Unfortunately, `catch` in my code doesn't seem to catch the exception. The exception is `HRESULT:0x80072F30 The text associated with this error code could not be found.`, by the way. Am I missing something like the exception is uncaughtable?

```
auto httpClient = ref new HttpClient();
auto get_operation = httpClient->GetAsync(ref new Uri(url), HttpCompletionOption::ResponseContentRead);
get_operation->Progress = progressHandler;
auto response = create_task(get_operation).then([](task<HttpResponseMessage^> previousTask)
{
    try
    {
        return previousTask.get();
    }
    catch (Exception^ ex)
    {
        // Some how this does not catch
        OutputDebugString(("Exception: " + ex->Message)->Data());
        return (HttpResponseMessage^)nullptr;
    }
}).get();
// At this point, I expect either a fully read response or response=nullptr
// Code to write to file is omitted
```

**EDIT**: ~~I tested the official Microsoft's [HttpClient sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664) which apparently use similar code. Apparently, the same crash occurs in that app when there is no network connection. This sort of confirms that the defect is in the OS side and there's nothing one can do about it.~~

**EDIT**: It turns out that I thought the exception was not caught because Visual Studio pops up a dialog and I assume that means in reality the exception crashes the app i.e. when it is not launched via VS. I read the pop up message carefully and realize that VS prompts on every Exception thrown unless configured not to do so; pressing [Continue] button on the dialog goes to the `catch` clause. Launching app from Start menu poses no problem.

Comment: Is this is a real device or emulator? WiFi switch off or WiFi switch on with issues somewhere else in the network?

Comment: @kiewic This is tested on my Windows 8.1 laptop, not on an emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this code is called from the UI thread then remove the `get()` call from the last line of this code. You can't do that in a UI thread.

Otherwise your code works fine for me with Airplane mode turned on; as expected I catch the exception in the handler. The exception has an `HResult` of `0x80072f30`, which is documented on the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn298645.aspx) as **ERROR_WINHTTP_NO_CM_CONNECTION**

Comment: It turns out that I thought the exception was not caught because Visual Studio pops up a dialog and I assume that means in reality the exception crashes the app [if it is not launched via VS]. I read the pop up message carefully and realize that VS prompts on every `Exception` thrown [unless configured not to do so]; pressing [Continue] button on the dialog goes to the `catch` clause. Launching app from Start menu poses no problem.